# In React applications, does the front-end receive the original React code or plain html?

Tags: reactjs

Does the browser receive the React code and render it into plain html on the front-end, or is the react code rendered into plain html on the back-end and the browser just receives this plain html from the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In vanilla React applications (which are not using [server-side rendering](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/server-side-rendering-your-react-app-in-three-simple-steps-7a82b95db82e/#:%7E:text=In%20Client%2Dside%20rendering%2C%20your,The%20output%20is%20HTML%20content.)), there are 2 options:

- Compile the React code (JSX) down to plain JavaScript during the build process. For example, `<h1>` will turn into `React.createElement('h1')`. (This build process only occurs when the programmer(s) make a change to the code.) The client then gets sent the transpiled vanilla code. This is by far the most common technique.
- Don't pre-process the JSX at all; instead, send it to the client without changes, and have the client process the JSX markup into runnable JavaScript. The client can process the JSX through [Babel Standalone](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone). This is unusual because it requires quite a lot of overhead for the client, but is occasionally useful (like for Stack Snippets here on Stack Overflow).

Here's an example of the use of Babel Standalone to compile and run JSX purely on the client-side:

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-standalone@6.10.3/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
const App = () => {
  return 'app';
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
</script>

<div class="react"></div>
```

But occasionally applications use server-side rendering instead, in which the logic is run primarily on the server, and then the server sends the plain HTML markup to the client, and the client displays it. A common framework used to accomplish this is [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/).